# Argument of type 'null' is not assignable on click event type Array. Can't find my answer in similar questions

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I need some help with my project. I am getting an error on **(click)="onOpenModal(null, 'add')** function call part. As It is an open modal, so I don't have the employee yet. It will be added on the UI, so I added null. But I am getting the error of stating that, Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Employee'. Here are my codes:

**app.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;">Employee System</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
           <a class="nav-link" (click)="onOpenModal(null, 'add')">Add Employee <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input type="search" (ngModelChange)="searchEmployees(key.value)" #key="ngModel" ngModel
         name="key" id="searchName" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search employees..." required>
     </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container" id="main-container">
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let employee of employees" class="col-md-6 col-xl-3">
     <div class="card m-b-30">
        <div class="card-body row">
           <div class="col-6">
              <a href=""><img src="{{employee.imageUrl}}" alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-60"></a>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6 card-title align-self-center mb-0">
              <h5>{{employee.name}}</h5>
              <p class="m-0">{{employee.jobTitle}}</p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
           <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-envelope float-right"></i>{{employee.email}}</li>
           <li class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-phone float-right"></i>Phone : {{employee.mobileNo}}</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body">
           <div class="float-right btn-group btn-group-sm">
              <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'edit')" class="btn btn-primary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> </a>
              <a (click)="onOpenModal(employee, 'delete')" class="btn btn-secondary tooltips" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Add Employee Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addEmployeeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addEmployeeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="addEmployeeModalLabel">Add Employee</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddEmployee(addForm)">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="name">Name</label>
             <input type="text" ngModel name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email">Email Address</label>
             <input type="email" ngModel name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="phone">Job title</label>
             <input type="text" ngModel name="jobTitle" class="form-control" id="jobTile" placeholder="Job title" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="phone">Phone</label>
             <input type="text" ngModel name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="phone">Image URL</label>
             <input type="text" ngModel name="imageUrl" class="form-control" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Image URL" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" id="add-employee-form" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             <button [disabled]="addForm.invalid" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Save changes</button>
          </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public employees: Employee[] = [];
  public editEmployee!: Employee;
  public deleteEmployee!: Employee;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getEmployees();
  }

  public getEmployees(): void {
    this.employeeService.getEmployees().subscribe(
      (response: Employee[]) => {
        this.employees = response;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  public onAddEmployee(addForm: NgForm): void {
    document.getElementById('add-employee-form')?.click();
    this.employeeService.addEmployee(addForm.value).subscribe(
      (response: Employee) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getEmployees();
        addForm.reset();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
        addForm.reset();
      }
    );
  }

  public onUpdateEmployee(employee: Employee): void {
    this.employeeService.updateEmployee(employee).subscribe(
      (response: Employee) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getEmployees();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  public onDeleteEmployee(employeeId: number): void {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(employeeId).subscribe(
      (response: void) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.getEmployees();
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }

  public searchEmployees(key: string): void {
    console.log(key);
    const results: Employee[] = [];
    for(const employee of this.employees) {
      if(employee.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.email.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.mobileNo.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      || employee.jobTitle.toLowerCase().indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
        results.push(employee);
      }
    }

    this.employees = results;
    if(results.length === 0 || !key) {
      this.getEmployees();
    }
  }

  public onOpenModal(employee: Employee, mode: string): void {
    const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.type = 'button';
    button.style.display = 'none';
    button.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
    if(mode === 'add') {
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#addEmployeeModal');
    }

    if(mode === 'edit') {
      this.editEmployee = employee;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#updateEmployeeModal');
    }

    if(mode === 'delete') {
      this.deleteEmployee = employee;
      button.setAttribute('data-target', '#deleteEmployeeModal');
    }

    container?.appendChild(button);
    button.click();
  }
}
```

I am new to Angular and need help with it as I am using the latest Angular version 15, so many things are different from the earlier versions. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered changing `onOpenModal(employee: Employee, ` to `onOpenModal(employee: Employee|null, `?

Comment: I invite you to use one of angular's library like ngx-bootstrap (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/modals?tab=overview)  or ng-bootstrap (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)  those libraries make modals easy and provide pretty qood features

Comment: @RockySims Yes I tried adding Employee | null but it gives the error for edit and delete part of the employee.

Answer (score 0):

because you declared

```js
public onOpenModal(employee: Employee, mode: string): void
```

so a value of `null` is not accepted, please pass in a valid parameter

Comment: Can you please explain with the reference of my code. I am trying to implement the functionality of adding a new employee. As soon as the Add Employee would be clicked it will open the form for adding the employee. Since it is an open modal, so I won't be having the employee in the start as I am creating one. So, I put up null. I have added the code for adding employee above in app.component.html